# Change reset password URL returned by wp_lostpassword_url() via plugin

Tags: plugin-development

With a plugin how would you change the URL returned by wp_lostpassword_url()?

The function wp_lostpassword_url() returns the URL where users can reset their password.

[Function Reference/wp lostpassword url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_lostpassword_url)

Comment: I also recomend this article, it helped me a lot https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-3-password-reset--cms-23811

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Just check the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L507):

```
515         /**
516          * Filter the Lost Password URL.
517          *
518          * @since 2.8.0
519          *
520          * @param string $lostpassword_url The lost password page URL.
521          * @param string $redirect         The path to redirect to on login.
522          */
523         return apply_filters( 'lostpassword_url', $lostpassword_url, $redirect );
```

There is a `lostpassword_url` filter that should do exactly what you are asking.

```
function passurl_wpse_208054($lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
  return 'http://path/to/login/url';
}
add_filter('lostpassword_url', 'passurl_wpse_208054', 10, 2);
```